# Prompt does not notice if statement change

Tags: javascript, if-statement, prompt

Please help. when running the code with an console.log statement it puts numbers in prompt snd then logs the answer separately, return statement is invalid apparently.

```
prompt("You begin to move but as you evade most of the bullets some of them hit your " +          bodyPart + " you begin to feel the blood shushing out, As people realize what happened there begins to be chaos. You look at the direction of the bullets to find 3 guys with heavy weaponry. They are almost done reloading. will you take COVER behind a table, RUN out of the place, or... suddenly you hear the girl telling you 'Take cover'... FIGHT them?").toUpperCase()

var bodyPart = Math.random()
                            if (bodyPart > .75){
                                bodyPart = "Right Arm"
                            }
                            else if (bodyPart > .50){
                                bodyPart= "Left Arm"
                            }
                            else if (bodyPart >.25){
                               bodyPart = "Right Leg"
                            }
                            else{
                              bodyPart = "Left Leg"
                            }
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive, possibly post the entire code, and maybe even post a jsfiddle showing the issue  live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your commands so you pprint the body part *after* you pick it. Right now you are printing the penultimate bodypart.

```
var bodyPartRoll = Math.Random();
var bodyPart;
if (bodyPartRoll > 0.75.){
   bodyPart = "Right Arm";
}else if(...){
   ...
}

prompt(bodyPart)
```

I also created a separate varialbe to store the result of Math.Random(). This isn't required but I think its confusing to use one variable for two things. Additionally, I would recommend adding semicolons at the end of your lines if you don't know how automatic semicolon insertions works in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use two variables. One called randomNumber and one called bodyPart. Then you won't be changing types and you should also have a clearer distinction between the two.